# CSS- Internal style sheet works. External doesn't. Weird Behavior

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap and ran into a strange problem. I am trying to include a cool hover effect for a facebook png image.

Everything works fine when I put the CSS in the  as an internal style rule. It won't work when I put it in an external style sheet.

All the paths are working because I have been successfully overriding the default bootstrap CSS rules.

With an external style sheet the image link is there but the image does not display. Kind of hard to explain. Not sure what to do?

http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/394/edit?html,css

Here is a link to the website where I got the html/css from. http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css3-ro...l-media-icons/
Like I said. Everything works internally. Just not externally....

Comment: Have you tried giving !important to the rules that you want to be applied? May not be the best solution but atleast you'll know if the bootstrap rule is still overriding your new rule.

Comment: in your bin, two of the resources are unavialable. one is bootstrap and other one is  facebook-hover.png.

Comment: Use `background: url(../img/facebook-hover.png);`

Answer (score 0):

Try the bootstrap cdn (code copied direct from Bootstrap).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. I changed the path to ../img/facebook-hover.png and it worked.Thanks!